# How to call other functions of same services in ionic (angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I am working on a mobile app using ionic framework. I have created a common Utility services like this

```
 .service('CommonUtilityService', function($q) {
        return {
            parseJsonDate:function(jsonDate){
                var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
                var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

                if (parts[2] == undefined)
                    parts[2] = 0;

                if (parts[3] == undefined)
                    parts[3] = 0;

                return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
            },
            daysBetween:function(date1String, date2String){
                var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                var ONE_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;

                var d1 = new Date(date1String);
                var d2 = new Date(date2String);
                var d1_ms = d1.getTime() - d1.getTimezoneOffset() * ONE_MINUTE;
                var d2_ms = d2.getTime() - d2.getTimezoneOffset() * ONE_MINUTE;

                return Math.floor(d1_ms - d2_ms/ONE_DAY);
            },
            getNumberOfDays:function(jsonDate){
               // var date = parseJsonDate(jsonDate);
                var date = new Date();
                var today = new Date();
                return this.daysBetween(today,date);
            }
        }
    })
```

When I am trying to call daysBetween function inside getNumberOfDays function it is giving error

```
this.daysBetween is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me how can I call daysBetween function inside getNumberOfDays function.

Comment: Try this CommonUtilityService.daysBetween(today,date)

Comment: Already tried but didn't work. It gave CommonUtilityService not defined error.

Comment: Try this : Create a variable in your function like this :
var selfFunction = this; and do return selfFunction.daysBetween(today,date);

Comment: Tried it already but same error.

Comment: how did you call the `getNumberOfDays` function?

Comment: could you make me a plunker to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [**Service doesn't return a object where Factory return an object**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/28262966#28262966). You could try refactored service like this

> **Service**
>
> A service is a constructor function which creates the object using the
>   new keyword. You can add properties and functions to a service object
>   by using the this keyword. Unlike a factory, it doesn't return
>   anything (it returns an object which contains method).

**Code**

```
 .service('CommonUtilityService', function($q) {
     var CommonUtilityService = this;
     CommonUtilityService.parseJsonDate = function(jsonDate) {
         var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
         var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

         if (parts[2] == undefined)
             parts[2] = 0;

         if (parts[3] == undefined)
             parts[3] = 0;

         return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2] * 3600000 + parts[3] * 60000);
     }
     CommonUtilityService.daysBetween = function(date1String, date2String) {
         var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
         var ONE_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;

         var d1 = new Date(date1String);
         var d2 = new Date(date2String);
         var d1_ms = d1.getTime() - d1.getTimezoneOffset() * ONE_MINUTE;
         var d2_ms = d2.getTime() - d2.getTimezoneOffset() * ONE_MINUTE;

         return Math.floor(d1_ms - d2_ms / ONE_DAY);
     }
     CommonUtilityService.getNumberOfDays = function(jsonDate) {
         // var date = parseJsonDate(jsonDate);
         var date = new Date();
         var today = new Date();
         return CommonUtilityService.daysBetween(today, date);
     }
 })
```

Comment: @NeelKamal take a look at the added link..which will give you better idea about the service & factory

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Pattern Three: Hybrid/Facade** so in this you have to use **this** as Explained by @pankajparkar

OR

```
    .service('CommonUtilityService', function($q) {

               var parseJsonDate = function(jsonDate){
                    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
                    var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

                    if (parts[2] == undefined)
                        parts[2] = 0;

                    if (parts[3] == undefined)
                        parts[3] = 0;

                    return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
                },

               var getNumberOfDays = function(jsonDate){
                   // var date = parseJsonDate(jsonDate);
                    var date = new Date();
                    var today = new Date();
                    return this.daysBetween(today,date);
                }
               return {
                 parseJsonDate:  parseJsonDate,
                 getNumberOfDays:  getNumberOfDays
                }
 })
```